# Unable to build metal library with iOS SDK 11.4

Tags: ios, macos, sdk, metal, ios11.4

I am trying to launch my application on iPad pro and getting an error when trying to create a new library with dispatched data as shown in the below image
[Error on creating new library with existing built .metallib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxM4A.png)

```
The library format is not supported or was built with old version of the tools
```

Here is the .metal code with which I am getting this error:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
#include <simd/simd.h>

using namespace metal;


struct VtxIn
{
packed_float2 pos;
packed_float2 uv0;
};

struct VtxOut
{
float4 pos [[position]];
float2 uv0;
};


vertex VtxOut MainVS    (   device VtxIn*   iVtxA   [[ buffer(0) ]],
                        uint            iIdx    [[ vertex_id ]])
{
VtxOut oVtx;

oVtx.pos = float4( iVtxA[iIdx].pos, 0.0, 1.0 );
oVtx.uv0 = iVtxA[iIdx].uv0;

return oVtx;
}

fragment float4 MainPS  (   VtxOut           iVtx       [[ stage_in]],
                        texture2d<float> iTex2D     [[ texture(0) ]],
                        sampler          iSampler2D [[ sampler(0) ]] )
{
    return iTex2D.sample( iSampler2D, iVtx.uv0 );
};
```

Comment: How did you build the .metallib? What commands? On what versions of macOS and Xcode? The data object you're using is the verbatim contents of the .metallib file?

Comment: @KenThomases to build metal library I am using bin files directly from the Xcode iOS sdk. MacOS 10.13 and Xcode is 9.4. And I am not sure about the verbatim contents

Comment: Show the specific compilation and link commands you're using to create the .metallib file.

Comment: @KenThomases Here are the three commands that I am using: 1. xcrun --sdk iphoneos metal -arch air64 -emit-llvm -c -ffast-math -std=ios-metal1.0 "some defines" -o /path/to/out/dir /path/to/source 2. xcrun --sdk iphoneos metal-ar rc /path/to/out/ar/dir /path/to/out/air/dir 3. xcrun --sdk iphoneos metallib -o /path/to/out/lib /path/to/out/air/dir

Comment: Can you try skipping the metal-ar step and directly giving the .air file as an input to metallib?

Comment: @danger ranger that I have tried already and it's working fine... Thanks for the suggestion